# Are there available temporal planners that work properly on Linux?

Tags: planning, pddl

I've been searching the web for a planner that supports temporal planning, specifically compatible with PDDL 2.2.
My machine runs Ubuntu bionic (18.04).

I was trying to use LPG-td planner, which strangely interpreted the planning problem as non-temporal (although it included the requirements for temporal planning in the correct syntax).

I couldn't find any planners that would compile on my machine or support the above requirements other than LPG-td.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While the web site for the Temporal track of the International Planning Competition 2018 is down, some information about it can be found
[here](https://www.nms.kcl.ac.uk/andrew.coles/PlanningCompetitionAAAISlides.pdf).
In 2018, there were 4 temporal planners, with TemPorAl showing best performance overall. You can find the instructions [here](https://icenamor.github.io/portfolio/Temporal/).

The code of the planners submitted to the Temporal Track of IPC 2018 can be found here: [CP4TP](https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-temporal/team1), [TFLAP](https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-temporal/team2), [TemPorAl](https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-temporal/team3), [popcorn-base](https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-temporal/team4), and the baseline [Optic](https://bitbucket.org/ipc2018-temporal/team5). All these planners should work under linux.